# Multiple alias for single page

Tags: pages

I have a requirement of displaying a same page for two url's. For example I have a page with url http://www.example.com/cleaning. Also I have a menu with few city names. I wish to have the same page displayed for url http://www.example.com/cityname/cleaning (should not redirect) and want to replace some text in the page with the city name. I dont want to create the same page under all cities for this.

Any solution?